# como saber cuantas gano X u O en juego 3 rayas o Gato?

Tags: java

Éste es mi código de gato o llamado 3 en raya. Quisiera ponerle un contador de cuántas ganadas llevan X y O, y luego pasarlas a una base de datos,  pero ya le he intentado y no puedo.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor o por lo menos explicarme?

```
public class Gato extends javax.swing.JFrame {




    public Gato() {
        initComponents();
    }
    public static String []atic = new String[9];
    String ch = "X";

    int cnt =0;


    public static void IniciarTablero(){



        //Limpia el arreglo para que no tenga ningun dato
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            atic[i]="";
        }
    }




    public  boolean HasWinner(){

        return((atic[0] == atic[1]  && atic[0] == atic[2] && atic[2] != "") ||
            (atic[3] == atic[4]  && atic[3] == atic[5] && atic[3] != "") ||
        (atic[6] == atic[7]  && atic[6] == atic[8] && atic[6] != "") ||
        (atic[0] == atic[3]  && atic[0] == atic[6] && atic[0] != "") ||
        (atic[1] == atic[4]  && atic[1] == atic[7] && atic[1] != "") ||
        (atic[2] == atic[5]  && atic[2] == atic[8] && atic[2] != "") ||
        (atic[0] == atic[4]  && atic[0] == atic[8] && atic[0] != "") ||
        (atic[2] == atic[4]  && atic[2] == atic[6] && atic[2] != ""));
    }
    public void Move(int num){/
        cnt++;

        atic[num]=ch;
    if (HasWinner())

        {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Primera pregunta:** *Añadir un contador.*
Para añadir el contador necesitas crear 2 variables enteras que lleven el registro de las veces que cada uno gana:

```
private int winsX = 0;
private int winsO = 0;
```

Ya que tienes un mensaje que indica quien es el ganador, aprovecha ese lugar para; además de notificar quien ganó, aumentarle su contador de victorias.

En tu método `Move` (que no debería iniciar con mayúscula el nombre porque es un método no una clase) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (HasWinner()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El ganador es:" + ch, "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    //inicio de codigo nuevo
    if("X".equals(ch))
        winsX++;
    else
        winsO++;

    jLabel4.setText(String.valueOf(winsX));
    jLabel5.setText(String.valueOf(winsO));
    //fin de codigo nuevo
}
```

En resumen si el que gana es `X` aumentas su contador, en caso contrario aumentas el de su rival `O`, para que la pantalla se actualice entonces colocas la sentencia `...setText(String.valueOf(winsX))` y `...setText(String.valueOf(winsO))`

**Segunda pregunta:** *Guardarlo en una base de datos*
No dispongo de un código a mano, pero puedes hacerlo con una conexión simple mediante JDBC, te dejo este [ejemplo](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/tutorial-basico-jdbc/) que puede ayudarte.
Obviamente deberás tener una base de datos creada y con una tabla en donde almacenarás la información que te interesa almacenar.

Como observaciones generales te indico lo siguiente:

1. La cantidad ideal de operadores lógicos dentro de un `if` son 3, tienes más de 20. Intenta optimizar esa área de tu código como ejercicio adicional de afianzamiento. Pero funciona! Sí, pero debemos codificar de la manera más clara y mantenible posible.
2. Los nombres de métodos inicial con letra minúscula, por ejemplo `Move` debe ser `move`
3. El método `jButton1.disable();` está `deprecated` usa `jButton1.setEnabled(true);` para deshabilitar componentes.